# Excel crashes when comparing two columns VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns which I am comparing for identical entries, and pushing the matches to another column through Offset. When I run the macro I've built (off of some Microsoft canned code) it essentially freezes and crashes, since it is a nested for each loop based on cells that are used, I figured it would end upon reaching an empty cell, but I fear I may be in a infinite loop. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Dim myRng As Range
Dim lastCell As Long

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range

For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AT2:AT" & lastRow).Cells
    For Each d In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AU2:AU" & lastRow).Cells
        If c = d Then c.Offset(0, 1) = c
    Next d
Next c
```

Comment: you shouldn't use c to set an offset since you are using it in the loop, use a new range that is not used by the loop

Comment: `c.Offset(0, 1)` points to a cell in column AU !

Comment: How many rows? In other words what is lastrow?  It may not be an infinite loop but may take a few minutes depending on the number of rows.  Because your iterations are (lastrow -1)^2.

Comment: 50-100,000 rows, I thought this may be an issue as well.

Comment: your offset is correct.  it is moving 1 to the right.

Comment: 100,000 rows is 1,000,000,000 iterations, it is going to take a  few minutes to complete.  you may need to let it run.  Though it may be faster to do a one loop and use Range.Find instead of the second loop.

Comment: The information is variable from report to report, so the length in colums changes over time, hopefully it gets shorter, but I'm wondering if the for each is a bad idea and is what is tripping me up, we have some that take a few minutes to run, but this one just wrecks excel, and it won't recover.

Comment: Have a search for "Worksheet bloat" - if you've been affected by this then your used range will be much bigger than what you think it is. I would always use a wildcard search to find the true last row rather than using the used range.

Comment: I'll look at that, thanks!

Comment: I would recommend @ScottCraner 's approach of using range.find. You can learn more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

Comment: Just a quick note.. if you are running something that takes a while to complete, you might think it crashed/locked up when your Excel suddenly shows as (Not Responding).  It's really just very, very busy thinking about your data.  To prevent this, you can just add "DoEvents" somewhere in your loop.  This will let ti keep up with screen updates, etc while your code is running.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim lastRow, currentRow, compareRow As Long
Dim found As Boolean

lastRow = Range("AT2").End(xlDown).Row

For currentRow = 2 To lastRow
    compareRow = 2
    found = False
    Do While compareRow <= lastRow And Not found
        If Range("AT" & currentRow).Value = Range("AU" & compareRow).Value Then
            found = True
            Range("AV" & currentRow).Value = Range("AT" & currentRow).Value
        End If
        compareRow = compareRow + 1
        DoEvents
    Loop
Next currentRow
```

Rather than selecting ranges and then cycling through them, this does the same thing without needing to .Select anything.  It also breaks out of the inner loop early if it finds a match.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are multiple issues here:

1. Efficiency of the search method
2. Loss of responsiveness of Excel

You can dramatically improve the efficiency of the code if you can pull all values into arrays. This prevents the time spent by VBA in accessing the Excel Object model and back. Loss of responsiveness can be handled by using `DoEvents`. Try the code below. It may look longish but should be easy to understand.

```
    'Find last row
    Dim lastRow As Variant
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    'Create dynamic arrays
    Dim AT() As Variant: Dim AU() As Variant: Dim AV() As Variant
    ReDim AT(2 To lastRow): ReDim AU(2 To lastRow): ReDim AV(2 To lastRow)

    'Get all contents from Excel
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        AT(i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 46)
        AU(i) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 47)
    Next i

    'Do the comparison
    For c = 2 To lastRow

        For d = 2 To lastRow
            If AT(c) = AU(d) Then AV(c) = AT(c)
        Next d

        'Allow a brief breather to Excel once in a while (don't hang)
        If (c / 100) = Int(c / 100) Then DoEvents

    Next c

    'Place final contents to Excel
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 48) = AV(i)
    Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your loop:

```
Dim StartRange As Range, j As Long
Dim CompareRange As Range, i As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set StartRange = .Range("AT1", .Range("AT:AT").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious))
    Set CompareRange = .Range("AU1", .Range("AU:AU").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious))

    For Each i In StartRange
        i.Offset(, -8).Value = .Evaluate("IF(COUNTIF(" & CompareRange.Address(0, 0) & "," & i.Address(0, 0) & ")>0," & i.Value & ","""")")
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim CompareRange As Variant, To_Be_Compared As Variant, j As Variant, k As Variant

Range("AT2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Set To_Be_Compared = Range("AT2:" & Selection.Address)
Range("AU2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Set CompareRange = Range("AU2:" & Selection.Address)


To_Be_Compared.Select

    For Each j In Selection
        DoEvents
        For Each k In CompareRange
            If j = k Then j.Offset(0, 2) = j
        Next k
    Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work, after taking the suggestions and implementing them into my code, I was able to see where the mistake actually was, I was referencing the wrong column earlier in the code and through this, created no duplicate entries to match, so after fixing this, the matches now appear, I ended up offsetting them, and changing the value to "yes" to reflect the duplication in my chart.

Thank you all for the help.